# Alternative to the vpa() command

Tags: matlab

I have a version of matlab and I don't have the toolbox for vpa().
Is there an alternative so that I can see the numbers with more precision?

I have tried doing:

format long but it's not quite the same

Comment: What precision do you need? Note that MATLAB's *display* of data is not the same as how it's stored.

Comment: Do the double/int64 types lack the necessary precision, or are you just having difficulty displaying all of the significant figures?

Comment: 32 sig figs like vpa, i just want to display it

Comment: Sorry, if you need to do math with that many significant figures then I don't know of an easy MATLAB solution without vpa.